# how to change label content based on progress percentage

Tags: c#

In my project I am just copying some files from source to destination. During the copying files, I increase the progress value. Now, I want to add a label content, that would be "Copying" during the copy and Then that would be "completed" after completing the file copy. My code was not working.

```
      <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Label">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProgressPercentage}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProgressPercentage}" Value="100">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Completed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>                    
            </StackPanel.Resources >
            <Label Content="Copying Files" Height="30" Width="100"/>
        </StackPanel >
```

Comment: You need to add more explanations and maybe more codes to your question in order to make it clear

Comment: I hope you updating ProgressPercentage. For progress bar are you updating in the background thread? If yes then you need to use dispatcher to update anything on main thread

Comment: Please be more specific, and include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you are having. The little bit of XAML you've shown here would seem to be do what you want, assuming the `ProgressPercentage` value does reach `100`. So presumably that's not happening. But without a better code example, it's not possible to identify whatever mistake you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use background worker to update the progress while processing.

Define the background worker :

```
 private BackgroundWorker SyncBgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Add the required events for the background worker

```
SyncBgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(SyncBgWorkerOnDoWork);// the process should be here
            SyncBgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);// if the process completed do this
            SyncBgWorker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;//while processing do this
SyncBgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
            SyncBgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;//to get the progress
```

The Events/Methods

```
 private void SyncBgWorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
        {
          //some codes
          SyncBgWorker.ReportProgress(10);//to update the progress value
         //some codes
          SyncBgWorker.ReportProgress(50);//to update the progress value
         //some codes
          SyncBgWorker.ReportProgress(100);//to update the progress value
        }

private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var objProgressBar = (ProgressBar)this.GetTemplateChild("PrgBarSyncProgress");
            UpdateProgressBarDelegate updatePbDelegate = new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(objProgressBar.SetValue);
            Dispatcher.Invoke(updatePbDelegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { ProgressBar.TagProperty, "Synchronizing " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%" });
        }
```

don't forget to change the name of your progress bar 'PrgBarSyncProgress'